# How you connect a line to a rectangle in figma?

Tags: figma

In Power Point you can connect a line to a shape on any of its corners or edges. When you move the shape around, the line's end moves with it.

Can you do this in figma?

Comment: You can't connect a line to a rectangle in vector image editing generally. Vectors can only have a start and end point, and paths can be open or closed shapes. You can't join an open path to a closed path (such as a rectangle). However, Inkscape has a connector tool which can be used for flow charts. You might be better looking for dedicated flow chart software TBH.  You also can't compare software like PowerPoint to vector image editors. They aren't the same thing at all.

Comment: [See Inkscape example](https://imgur.com/kPS51DD), using connectors

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like [FigJam](https://www.figma.com/figjam/) (figma's new whiteboard tool) might be a good tool for flowcharts.

You can also select both the line and the rectangle and Group them together (right-click > Group Selection OR Cmnd+G / Ctrl+G)

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Figma is not a dedicated flowchart tool (at least not so far).

Alternatively you can use a plugin like Flowkit or one of the zillion flowchart kits with predefined line shapes. But even with those you simply position your shapes and lines, it won't stay connected like in powerpoint or omnigraffle.

Comment: That would be nice if they add an ability to do that in Figma.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of templates on Figma's website
https://www.figma.com/templates/flowchart-maker/

Also there is a plugin for that works very good
https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/733902567457592893/Autoflow